# cascading dropdown list for custom field in kentico cms

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I have added two new custom field in CMS_USER table.

Both filed is integer type and Form control is Drop-Down list type.

currently both dropdown list is filled by SQL query in Editing control settings.

I want to implement functionality as when user select any value from first dropdown list than second dropdown list will fill according condition of selected value of first dropdown.

second dropdown list will fill on first dropdown selected index changed.

How can I do this.

Path is as **Administrator login** - >**CMSSiteManager**-> **Administration** -> **Users** -> **edit user**-> **Custom field**.

First dropdown is **CompanyName** and second is **CompanyAddress**

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only think that comes into my mind (if you don't want to create custom controls) is that macros are being resolved within SQL queries. So it should be possible to use following

```
SELECT AddressID, AddressName FROM TableWithAdresses WHERE AddressCompanyID = {% EditedObject.GetValue("CompanyID") %}
```

as a query for second dropdown list. Use integrated SQL debug (CMS Site Manager -> Administration -> System -> Debug -> SQL debug) to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks rocky, it is working fine for loading page at first time. but when I change index of first dropdown than it is taking old selected value of first dropdown so it is not updating second dropdown list.

Comment: That's probably because the value in EditedObject is not being changed.  You will probably have to live with it or make your own form control. I have no more ideas. :/

Comment: Thanks rocky, I am trying with creating custom form.

Answer (score 1):

You can try custom form control. 
see http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/5_5r2/devguide/index.html?developing_form_controls.htm